# Is there way to know cmdlet version in Powershell for backward compatibility?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Say you are scripting in Powershell 4.0 environment and you want to make sure the script works in Powershell 3.0. How do you ensure its backward compatible?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok the question as phrased is a little more specific into what you are looking for. Sounds like you are asking for [requires](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847765.aspx).

> The`#Requires` statement prevents a script from running unless the Windows 
>       PowerShell **version**, modules, snap-ins, and module and snap-in version
>       prerequisites are met. If the prerequisites are not met, Windows PowerShell
>       does not run the script.

That way, while you are scripting, you can enforce the functional version of your script.

```
#Requires -Version 3.0
```

So now while you are building and debugging your script you know that it will work on systems with at least 3.0. It recognizes minor builds as well if that matters.

---

I recently came across this requirement for my own needs and realize now that what I suggested up above will not get you the exact results I think you are looking for. What you should do instead is when you run your script call a new PowerShell session and use the `-Version` switch which *Starts the specified version of Windows PowerShell*([TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh847736.aspx)).

So when you are testing your script run it like this:

```
powershell -Version 2 -File myscript.ps1
```

Comment: In hindsight this might be flawed for what the OP wants since _-Version Specifies the __minimum__ version of Windows PowerShell that the script 
      requires._

Comment: Using #requires is a good idea to make sure the script is only run when given a minimum version of PowerShell, but it does NOT ensure it's compatible. You still have to write the code in such a way, and test it in both version to make sure it works in both. I will admit that PowerShell 3.0 and 4.0 compatibility is pretty good, but if you wanted to have a script that needs to run in 2.0, for example, you'd certainly have to code some things differently (ie. staying away from features and functionality that was introduced after 2.0, or in this case 3.0)

Comment: @campbell.rw Yeah... that is why I added a proper answer for what I think the OP wants in the second half of my answer.

Comment: Yup, good stuff, was just helping to clarify in case people might get confused.

Answer (score 5):

Here an example to get the Version of "Get-ChildItem":

```
(Get-Command Get-ChildItem).Version
```

Comment: In PS 3 & 4 there is no `Version` property in th `Get-Command` result.

Comment: You are right.  I forgot the cross check with my PS3 Environment.  Excuse me place.

Answer (score 0):

using get-module of the required Command, you can do it like:

```
(Get-Module (Get-Command Get-NetTCPConnection).Source).PowerShellVersion
```

For clarification:

- `(Get-command <your cmdlet>). Source` gives you the installed location