# How to tell required version of PowerShell to run a command?

Tags: powershell

For example what is required to run:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIPAddress
```

How can i check if Get-NetAdapter requires PowerShell 5 or PowerShell 2?

Also how can i check additional requirements like:

- only Windows 2012 and newer
- existence of service (like Get-ClusterGroup requires Cluster Service)

Is there a way to gather those information within PowerShell or any good website?

Comment: Are you after a programmatic/automatic way of doing so, or purely looking for a reference of such information?

Comment: I'm looking for reliable source of information. If it can be automated even better.

Comment: Check this post : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312932/is-there-way-to-know-cmdlet-version-in-powershell-for-backward-compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312932/is-there-way-to-know-cmdlet-version-in-powershell-for-backward-compatibility)

Comment: Thanks ManuP, but i still need information like get-netadapter requires Windows 2012 even if it only need PS2

Comment: Realistically, no. If the documentation doesn't mention it, you're out of luck. Scripts can indicate what version of PowerShell they require and even what modules they require, but they are not obligated to do so and can simply fail if the requirements are not met, and there is no way at all for scripts to indicate what version or installed features of the OS they require. You can work these things out yourself on a case-by-case basis, but there's no easy repository, let alone one available to automation.

Comment: Cmdlets will have a minimum required version of PowerShell but rarely a minimum OS. Windows _ships_ with a specific version of PowerShell, but it can be upgraded to a newer version so often cmdlets will run on older OS's if PS is upgraded on them.

Comment: @JamesC. some cmdlets do require certain version of Windows though, because they rely on underlying functionality not available on earlier versions. `Get-NetAdapter` is a good example of this, only works on Windows 8/Windows 2012 or newer regardless of what PS version you install on earlier OSes.

Comment: In the cases where I've encountered an OS dependency, I've also found that the cmdlet isn't listed when you do a `Get-Command -Module ...` against the module that nominally exports that command - and if it's a core command (i.e., shipped with PowerShell or WMF), it still won't be a found command if you try to execute it on an OS that doesn't support it. For example, on Windows 7, even if you `Import-Module GroupPolicy`, you will not have the `Invoke-GPUpdate` cmdlet; that requires Windows 8/Server 2012 or later.